# Protobuf import failure

Tags: import, grpc, protocol-buffers

Does anyone know where I can find an example of a gRPC protobuf file that imports from a different file and uses a protobuf message in a return? I can't find any at all.

I have a file...

```
syntax = "proto3";
package a1;
import "a.proto";
service mainservice {
  rpc DoSomething(...) returns (a.SomeResponse) {}


}
```

a.proto is also in the same directory and also compiles by itself. The error messages I'm getting are:
  `"a.SomeResponse" is not defined.`
  `mainfile.proto: warning: Import a.proto but not used.`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Found the answer... need to make sure the package name of a.proto is used when specifying the object imported (eg: a_package_name.SomeResponse). Example:

base.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "Api.Protos";
package base;
message BaseResponse {
    bool IsSuccess = 1;
    string Message = 2;
}
```

user.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "Protos/base.proto";
option csharp_namespace = "Api.Protos";
package user;

message UserCreateResponse {
    base.BaseResponse response = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems import from root but not current proto file's folder. So you need add 'Proto/a.proto' if all your proto files are under Proto folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).